# How do I make a Tkinter pop-up menu disappear when I press a key?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, binding, menu

I've been trying to make a Tkinter pop-up menu (that appears when the user releases their mouse button on a password_label) disappear when the user presses the CTRL key.

Here is the code that's causing the issue:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

def show_copy_button(event, copy) -> None:
    copy.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root - 30)

def hide_copy_menu(event) -> None:
    print('hide_copy_menu function executed.')
    copy_menu.unpost()

window.bind_all('<Control_L>', lambda event: hide_copy_menu(None))

copy_menu = tk.Menu(window, tearoff=False)
copy_menu.add_command(label='Copy')

password_label = tk.Text(window, width=100, height=1,
borderwidth=0, font='Consolas 11')
password_label.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
password_label.bind('<ButtonRelease>', lambda event: show_copy_button(event, copy_menu))

window.mainloop()
```

I tried binding the hide_copy_menu function to the <Control_L> event on the password_label, on the input_box, on the window, and focusing the keyboard, but nothing worked. It seems that when the menu pops up, the keyboard is focused somewhere I can't get to, and somewhere from where I can't find a way to get the <Control_L> event to execute the function.

I'm looking to make the pop-up menu disappear when the user presses CTRL, because the CTRL + C combination does not. Why does it not work? I believe it's again because of the keyboard being focused somewhere I can't get to.

Comment: instead of using menu you can use a [toplevel window as a workaround](https://textdoc.co/vJyYm6riM2D9SnOX).

Comment: I need the text to remain selected. I decided to make the pop-up menu only appear when the user right-clicks. This way, the CTRL + C combination still works, and the user can still copy.

Comment: Thank you very much anyway, though! I might use your solution in the future.